# Firefox Compatibility JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Having some trouble with JavaScript on Firefox. It works fine on IE and Chrome.

If you visit here: http://www.puretreetimber.co.uk/worktop Select a species, range and grade, then add a custom worktop, select a finish and then Step 6 will pop up, and thats the bit I'm having a problem with (Looks like http://puu.sh/81SYZ.jpg)

When you select a fabrication, it will add it to the cart, if you click it again, it will deselect it (Removing class 'active' from itself). On Firefox, this doesn't work.

Here is my JS function. This is called when .fabrication-child is clicked:
http://pastebin.com/4WcW0mzA

(Or line 243 on [scripts.js](http://www.puretreetimber.co.uk/js/scripts.js))

Note:
Code under the comment `//Set main fabrication image` is irrelevant to selecting/deselecting

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script doesn't work as expected on the following line because [FireFox doesn't support event.x](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent)

```
if(event.x < self.find(".qty").offset().left)
```

Use event.clientX instead of event.x to remedy this.

Changing line 19 to the following will make the code work also in FF:

```
if(event.clientX < self.find(".qty").offset().left)
```